# How to extract hours from time_t?

Tags: c, time, time-t

I want to extract hours, minutes and seconds as integer values from a time_t value representing seconds since epoch.

The value for hours is not correct. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[64];

    while (1) {
        time_t t = time(NULL);
        struct tm *tmp = gmtime(&t);

        int h = (t / 360) % 24;  /* ### My problem. */
        int m = (t / 60) % 60;
        int s = t % 60;

        printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", h, m, s);

        /* For reference, extracts the correct values. */
        strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%H:%M:%S\n", tmp);
        puts(buf);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Output (the hour should be 10)

```
06:15:35
10:15:35

06:15:36
10:15:36

06:15:37
10:15:37
```

Comment: "int h = (t / 3600) % 24; ..." makes the _assumption_ the `time_t` is in integer seconds.   Although that is common, it is not defined to be so by C.  Use `gmtime()/localtime()` or `difftime()` for portable code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your call to `gmtime()` already does it, the resulting `struct tm` has all the fields. See [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gmtime).

In other words, just

```
printf("hours is %d\n", tmp->tm_hour);
```

I would argue that this is the proper way, since it avoids involving scarily large numbers to do the conversion manually in your code. It does so in the best of ways, by making it Someone Else's Problem (i.e., abstracting it away). So fix your code not by adding the missing `0`, but by using `gmtime()`.

Also think about timezones.

Comment: Thanks, but the question was: Why is the calculation not correct. (I agree that using struct tm is a better approach though).

Comment: @dannas: Cuz you are dividing as: t/360 where it should be t/3600 (remember 60 * 60)

Comment: Hm, the question actually was: "how extract hours from time_t" (in the problem spec I added the other question). Accepting the answer since it gives a good reason as to why I should avoid doing the conversion myself.

Answer (score 15):

```
int h = (t / 3600) % 24;  /* ### Your problem. */
```

Comment: Doh, why did I not see that obvious one?

Comment: I think that everyone sometimes looks at a bug and doesn't see it. It's often to me ;)